# other books, by other authors

Tags: punctuation

> 1. These are the books I wrote in this subject. There are other books**,** by other authors**,** on this subject as well.
> 2. These are the books I wrote in this subject. There are other books by other authors on this subject as well.

Which is correctly punctuated?

Comment: Can't see any reason to place a comma there.

Comment: @SovereignSun the commas set off a parenthetical observation, one could eliminate it and the sentence would still be grammatical.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes, but even in a formal style there'd probably be no comma.

Answer (score 2):

If I had to choose between the OP's two versions, I would opt for b. The only correction would be to replace the preposition "in" with "on".

- These are the books I wrote on this subject. There are other books by other authors on this subject as well.

The OP  could join the two separate clauses by using the adverb "however", and with a little tweaking, it could look like this:

> **Here** are the books I wrote **on** the subject; **however,** there are **others** by different authors as well.

Use the pronoun **others** to avoid repeating "books" in the same sentence.

Comment: Your phrase is indeed idiomatic and clear and if that was what the OP was after then your answer is much better than mine.

Comment: There are others by other authors on the same subject. is shorter....

Comment: @Lambie what happened to the first clause/sentence? I count 8 words in my answer if I exclude "however"

Comment: Sure.  OK. I would probably write: Here are my books on the subject. There are others by other authors.

Answer (score 1):

I can see no reason to place a comma there so I would put it this way:

- These are the books I wrote **on** this subject **but** there are other books by various other authors on this subject as well.

Comment: A bit too wordy for my liking.

Comment: I agree, but I wasn't pointing out brevity here, instead the connection and the idea in general.